# Installing and Using Redcarpet (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, markdown

I am trying to implement markdown into my rails app, and I came across [Redcarpet](https://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet) which seems to be what I'd like to use.  I have added the gem to my Gemfile and I have cloned the Redcarpet source from github.  How/where do I install the source now?

Also, I would like to add [GFM (github flavored markup)](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/) as well, where do I add the code presented in that link?

Thanks, please let me know if more details are required.

Comment: This Railscast should get you on the right track: http://railscasts.com/episodes/272-markdown-with-redcarpet